# How to read XML from C++ String containing XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I've string containing XML generated by C++ program. 
PHP executes my C++ code and should pass this XML to javascript.
But I am not sure how to do it. I've used exec,system methods in PHP to get this XML string. 
Please let me know how can I pass exact XML to javascript.

Comment: Printing out the XML should be enough, but more information about what you want would be nice. By Javascript you mean an AJAX request, a variable or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You question is very unconcrete, so I can only guess:

```
passthru($command)
```

See [`passthru`](http://php.net/passthru).

Comment: Thanks. I found tidy class in PHP (which is not enabled by default) very useful.